# Find error in analytic geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> Let $C:\frac{y^2}3-x^2=1$, and $F~(0,-2)$. Let $F\in l$, and $l\cap C=A$, $B$.
> Let $P~\left(0,\sqrt7\right)$. If the center of $(ABP)$ is on the $x$-axis.
> Find the slope of $l$.

I can let $l:y=kx-2$ because obviously $l:x=0$ doesn't work. Let $A~(x_1,kx_1-2)$, $B~(x_2,kx_2-2)$. Putting the functions of $l$ and $c$ together, we get
\[(k-3)x^2-4kx+1=0.\tag1\]
And $x_{1,2}$ are the roots of this quadratic function. In addition let $O~(t,0)$ the center of $(ABP)$. So $AO=BO=PO$. By Pythagorean theorem,
\[(x_1-t)^2+(kx_1-2)^2=(x_2-t)^2+(kx_2-2)^2=t^2+7.\]
Simplify to get that $x_{1,2}$ are the roots of the quadratic function
\[(k^2+1)x^2-(4k+2t)x-3=0.\tag2\]
Since $(1)$ and $(2)$ have the same roots, Vieta theorem yields
\[x_1x_2=\frac1{k-3}=\frac{-3}{k^2+1}.\]
But solving this doesn't give me the correct answer. There must be some mistake in my solution. Where?

Comment: What is meant by the "centre of $ABP$"? The angle? The triangle?

Comment: The center of $\odot(ABP)$, in another way of saying it. @ParclyTaxel

Comment: Can you write the correct answer?

Comment: @mathlove $\pm\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the following step :

> Putting the functions of $l$ and $c$ together, we get
> \[(k-3)x^2-4kx+1=0.\tag1\]

It should be
$$(\color{red}{k^2}-3)x^2-4kx+1=0$$

Then, you'll finally get
$$\frac{1}{k^2-3}=\frac{-3}{k^2+1}$$
Solving this gives $k=\pm\sqrt 2$.